# common config between multiple build steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

If i need to write a jenkins plugin with multiple build steps, is it possible for these build steps to share a common config (as in the common plugin detail from global.jelly) ?

Eg: Lets say my plugin adds the following new steps.. Build Step, Deploy Step, Test & Coverage step
All these three would have their own extension points in respective classes (PluginBuildStep, PluginDeployStep, PluginTestStep) and a common class PluginMain which has all the common properties and the global.jelly

I tried doing this, but i see 3 repititions of global.jelly sections on the global configurations section.. Any pointers on how this can be done ? or am i on the wrong track (ie. each build step should have its own configuration and should not be sharing configuration with other build steps..?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this by using Job Properties as explained here... [Can two different jenkins builders exist in the same hpi and share the same global configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754610/can-two-different-jenkins-builders-exist-in-the-same-hpi-and-share-the-same-glob/23309714#23309714)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the inheritance-plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/inheritance-plugin

This youtube video talks about inheriting build steps (at time 7m 20s):

http://youtu.be/DNUI7DRi6XE?t=7m20s