# Jenkins Plugin development, use one global config for two builders?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two builders within my plugin I am developing, I want them to share the same global config. I currently have a repeatable list of server details of which I currently can select which server I want to use from a drop down in builderA's config. I want to do the same for builderB's config, but this requirs me duplicating the global config from builderA and user filling out two lots of global config.

Is there anyway I can access builderA's global config? or make builderA's global config global....

I found this: [Can two different jenkins builders exist in the same hpi and share the same global configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754610/can-two-different-jenkins-builders-exist-in-the-same-hpi-and-share-the-same-glob) and copied it, to test, but it doesnt tell you how you can get globalField1 in the perform method of MyBuildStepAClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. I did it with the [selenium axis plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Axis+Plugin) where I needed the name of the selenium server kept in a related class

This is in groovy but is easy to convert.

```
//so we need this to get at the name of the selenium server in the global config
protected static Descriptor<? extends ComplexAxisDescriptor> getTopLevelDescriptor(){
    SeleniumAxis.DescriptorImpl sad = Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptor(SeleniumAxis.class)
    sad.load()
    return sad
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-axis-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/SeleniumDynamicCapability.groovy)

I think you will need to change the

```
<? extends ComplexAxisDescriptor>
```

to

```
<? extends Descriptor>
```

and use the descriptor for your class otherwise your methods will not be accessible